# Service names not getting resolved within Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, dns

As the title states, I am having an issue with resolving service names within my K8's cluster.

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52274134/connect-to-other-pod-from-a-pod) question, I created a busybox pod and tried to resolve an existing service name using `nslookup nginx-service`. I get the error: `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

I also tried the [instructions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) on the official K8's documentation on how to debug DNS issues. As it states, I tried to do an `nslookup kubernetes.default` but got the same error as before.

Listed below is some information:

1) Output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local 
reddog.microsoft.com
options ndots:5
```

2) Result of `kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns`

```
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-5c98db65d4-5nprd   1/1     Running   0          3d22h
coredns-5c98db65d4-5vw95   1/1     Running   0          3d22h
```

3) Output of `for p in $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name); do kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $p; done`

```
.:53
2019-07-22T18:39:37.208Z [INFO] CoreDNS-1.3.1
2019-07-22T18:39:37.208Z [INFO] linux/amd64, go1.11.4, 6b56a9c
CoreDNS-1.3.1
linux/amd64, go1.11.4, 6b56a9c
2019-07-22T18:39:37.208Z [INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 5d5369fbc12f985709b924e721217843
.:53
2019-07-22T18:39:37.245Z [INFO] CoreDNS-1.3.1
2019-07-22T18:39:37.245Z [INFO] linux/amd64, go1.11.4, 6b56a9c
CoreDNS-1.3.1
linux/amd64, go1.11.4, 6b56a9c
2019-07-22T18:39:37.245Z [INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 5d5369fbc12f985709b924e721217843
```

For what it's worth, since I know that the DNS server is at `10.96.0.10` when I try to ping that IP, I don't get a response.

EDIT:
Output of `dig @10.96.0.10 nginx-service`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3 <<>> @10.96.0.10 nginx-service
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: " DNS server is at 10.96.0.10 when I try to ping that IP, I don't get a response." ping is a poor troubleshooting tool. Try `dig @10.96.0.10 somename`. If you get a timeout, with and without `+tcp` then you have a network filtering problem or the DNS server just does not run (or not at this IP)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Hi. I edited my question with the output of the `dig` command. Please check. Also, I think DNS should run at this IP because its the DNS server specified in the `resolv.conf` file

Comment: Have you checked whether your NGINX pod is up and running, and is reachable via its IP address from toolbox Pod ?
1. kubectl get svc/nginx-service -o jsonpath='{.spec.clusterIP}'
2. curl <IP-address-from-above-command>

Comment: What Kubernetes setup you are working on, Managed by Cloud provider, On-Premise ?

Comment: I have the same problem. did you find any solution?

Comment: @florin very sorry for the late reply.. It turned out my cluster CDN was not working properly. I was using Calico. I uninstalled calico and installed Flannel. That worked.

Comment: I also have the same issue with Flannel.